# Vectorise Shortest Path Finding Algorithm Matlab

Tags: algorithm, matlab, for-loop, vectorization, dijkstra

I have an adjacency matrix `A` (`n`x`n`) and would like to construct a matrix `D` where `D(i,j)` is the graph distance from vertex `i` to vertex `j`. I'm currently using the [`graphshortestpath`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/bioinfo/ref/graphshortestpath.html) (in-built) Matlab function. I know I can do this with nested for-loops:

```
for i = 1:n, for j = 1:n
        D(i,j) = graphshortestpath(A,i,j);
end, end
```

Moreover, I can drop the inner for-loops:

```
for i = 1:n
        D(i,:) = graphshortestpath(A,i);
end
```

However, in my case `n` is going to get large, so I'd like to write this as

```
D(:,:) = graphshortestpath(A,:,:)
```

Unfortunately, this expression is meaningless to Matlab. Does anyone know how to solve this particular issue?

---

I realise that I could speed this up using `parfor`. However, I want to be calling this inside a `parfor` loop, so I can't do that. Moreover, if I could run the for loop on a fast GPU, then this would likely be fairly rapid; unfortunately, that's not possible for my set up.

Comment: Did you try [`graphallshortestpaths`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/bioinfo/ref/graphallshortestpaths.html)?

Comment: No, I didn't come across that in my search! That's exactly what I'm looking for, thank you!

Comment: I don't know how I didn't see that! It's even on the "see also" of `graphshortestpath` documentation. Well, at least you've saved me more time fruitlessly looking, so thank you! =D